# Finding what was selected in the combobox list using right-click

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I'm writing a Windows desktop app using C# and WPF. I've a combobox that is used to either type in a file path or to select from previously used file paths. The files in the list can become invalid if the file is deleted or the user entered a valid file but not the desired file. They've asked for a way to remove bad entries from the combobox drop-down list. They want to right-click on an item and select Remove from the context menu.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cbDocket" IsEditable="True">
   <ComboBox.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="Remove" Click="cbDocket_MenuItemRemove">/>
        </ContextMenu>
    </ComboBox.ContextMenu>
</ComboBo>
```

That's the easy part. What I cannot figure out is how to determine which item they selected. Searching hasn't found any suggestions that work. Any help would be appreciated. Is there another way to do this that would be easier? Oh yes, I fairly new to both C# and WPF.

Thanks, Brian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Context menus in WPF are pretty badly broken by design, so about half of all normal cases, anything you do that actually works is a kludge. I've come up with a few; here's another that's not really all that kludgey.

XAML:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cbDocket" IsEditable="True">
    <ComboBox.Resources>
        <ContextMenu x:Key="ItemMenu">
            <MenuItem Header="Remove" Click="MenuItem_Click" />
        </ContextMenu>
    </ComboBox.Resources>

    <!-- Some arbitrary random junk to display in the ComboBox -->
    <TextBlock Text="Foo" />
    <TextBlock Text="Bar" />
    <!-- End of arbitrary random junk -->

    <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
            <Setter 
                Property="ContextMenu" 
                Value="{StaticResource ItemMenu}" 
                />
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ComboBox>
```

Code behind:

```
private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //  This needs some null checking and a try catch, but this is the guts of it. 

    //  sender should be the MenuItem as well
    var menuItem = e.OriginalSource as MenuItem;

    //  Since we used ItemContainerStyle to give each ComboBoxItem its own 
    //  personal ContextMenu, each ContextMenu will have its PlacementTarget
    //  set to the ComboBoxItem that owns it. 
    var cbItem = (menuItem.Parent as ContextMenu).PlacementTarget as ComboBoxItem;

    //  ???
    //var dataItem = cbItem.DataContext;
}
```

You didn't mention how you're populating the combo box, so I don't know whether you've got `DataContext` set on the items or what. But once you have the `ComboBoxItem`, you can get there.

Comment: It works! The box is populated with what the user types or from a select button using OpenFileDialog. Don't know about DataContext. That's an advance topic I haven't learned yet.

Answer (score 1):

With the following program code you can add a context menu to a combo box. In this context menu a single item or all items of the combo box can be removed.

[image: Combo box with context menu]

```
private ComboBox FolderComboBox;
private ContextMenu FolderHistoryContextMenu;

...    

private void CreateFolderHistoryContextMenu()
{
  MenuItem RemoveFolderMenuItem, RemoveAllFoldersMenuItem;

  FolderHistoryContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
  RemoveFolderMenuItem = new MenuItem();
  RemoveFolderMenuItem.Header = "Remove folder";
  RemoveFolderMenuItem.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(RemoveFolderMenuItem_Click);
  FolderHistoryContextMenu.Items.Add(RemoveFolderMenuItem);
  RemoveAllFoldersMenuItem = new MenuItem();
  RemoveAllFoldersMenuItem.Header = "Remove all folders";
  RemoveAllFoldersMenuItem.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(RemoveAllFoldersMenuItem_Click);
  FolderHistoryContextMenu.Items.Add(RemoveAllFoldersMenuItem);

  // The context menu is assigned to each item in the list of the combo box and not to the combo box itself.
  if (FolderComboBox.ItemContainerStyle == null)
  {
    FolderComboBox.ItemContainerStyle = new Style(typeof(ComboBoxItem));
  }
  FolderComboBox.ItemContainerStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(ContextMenuProperty, FolderHistoryContextMenu));
}


private void RemoveFolderMenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  ComboBoxItem ClickedComboBoxItem = FolderHistoryContextMenu.PlacementTarget as ComboBoxItem;
  if (ClickedComboBoxItem != null)
  {
    object ComboBoxDataItem = ClickedComboBoxItem.DataContext;
    FolderComboBox.Items.Remove(ComboBoxDataItem);
  }
}


private void RemoveAllFoldersMenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  FolderComboBox.Items.Clear();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple ways of doing this.  Since you are using the `Click` event handler, then the `source` of the event is always the item that was clicked.  For example:

Xaml:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cbDocket" IsEditable="True">
    <ComboBox.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="Remove" Click="cbDocket_MenuItemRemove">/>
        </ContextMenu>
    </ComboBox.ContextMenu>
</ComboBo>
```

Xaml.cs:

```
private void cbDocket_MenuItemRemove(object source, EventArgs args)
{
    // Source is your item:
    cbDocekt.Items.Remove(cbDocket.SelectedItem);
}
```

Of course you can always obtain the selected item, or even change the selected item in the combo box using the `SelectedItem` property.

I'm assuming you are using code behind to do this.

Comment: When I try that, I find that `source` is the `MenuItem`, and  `((source as MenuItem).Parent as ContextMenu).PlacementTarget` is the `ComboBox`. Is that not what you saw when you tested it?

Comment: `source` is the `MenuItem`, which is what I expected from the example code given.  The `ComboBox` was given a name: `cbDocket` in the original code.  So the OP could go through the path you took to get to the ComboBox, or just access it directly.  There are even more ways of skinning this cat, but I chose to keep it as close to the provided code as possible.

Comment: After coming back to my answer and looking at it in more detail, I missed an important detail: the OP wanted to remove the selected item.  It's been a really long day...

Comment: My belief was that he wanted them to be able to click on arbitrary items in the dropdown, not merely the selected item. In fact I should check if my answer works for the selected item...

Comment: Whoops. It's an editable combobox; clicking on it when it's closed gets you the TextBox contxt menu, of course

Comment: I've had a few long days myself lately. Cheers!

Comment: Correct. I want the user to be able to hover over any item on the drop-down, right click and select Remove. That item is then removed from the list.

Ed's answer seems to be working. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add an event to track the mouse movement while the dropdown is open and use that when the remove is clicked.

```
    <ComboBox x:Name="cbDocket" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="33,30,0,269" Width="124" IsEditable="True">
        <ComboBox.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu Name="Menu">
                <MenuItem Header="Remove" Click="cbDocket_MenuItemRemove"/>
            </ContextMenu>
        </ComboBox.ContextMenu>
        <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
                <EventSetter Event="MouseMove" Handler="cbDocket_OnMouseMove" />
            </Style>
        </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle> 
</ComboBox>
```

Code behind:

```
ComboBoxItem cbiSelected = null;

private void cbDocket_MenuItemRemove(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    cbDocket.Items.Remove(cbiSelected);
}

private void cbDocket_OnMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    ComboBoxItem cbiHover = sender as ComboBoxItem;
    if (cbiHover.IsHighlighted)
    {//Verify the item is highlighted
        cbiSelected = cbiHover;
    }
}
```